# Does UIImage have a property which indicates whether it is Portrait or Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, orientation

Let's say you have a UIImage from the image picker controller. Does it have a property which one can check to see if the image is in portrait or landscape? In other words, to check if the height is bigger then the width. I looked at the reference, but didn't see anything there.

Comment: No, i dont think so. U will have to check the controller orientation.

Comment: Is checking the height against the width manually not an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `imageOrientation` but it seems that this code is more straight forward :

```
-(BOOL) isPortrait; {
    return image.height > image.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Yourimage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
NSLog(@"portrait");
}   
else if (yourimage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
NSLog(@"landscape");
}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Technically there are four orientations that corresponds to portrait image : UIImageOrientationDown, UIImageOrientationDownMirrored, UIImageOrientationUpMirrored and UIImageOrientationUp